# ssrs - redirecting url in windows server 2003

Tags: redirect, reporting-services, url-rewriting, windows-server-2003

SSRS reports have been migrated from old server to another.
Old Server is windows server 2003
On call of old server URL reports redirection is required to new server noting that IIS is not used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found Solution! 
Injected JavaScript code in ReportingService.js file that is found in URL

*D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportManager*

I was able to redirect all calls of old server URL to new server URL also I changed the URL to be by querystring.